# FLEX/BISON - How to convert user input to lowercase?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

How do I convert the user input to lowercase in Flex? Looked on line but didn't find anything helpful.

When I try to do this:

```
yylval.string = strdup(tolower( yytext) );
```

I get error stating: passing arg 1 of 'tolower' makes integer from pointer without a cast.

Thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 1):

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
%}
%%
[A-Z]    putchar(tolower(*yytext));
```

If you want to convert an entire string to lower case, you need to call `tolower` in a loop, as `tolower` only converts a single character:

```
for (i = 0; yytext[i]; i++)
    yytext[i] = tolower(yytext[i]);
yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using union. how would I change the case for this: yylval.str = strdup( yytext );

Comment: Your solution is good but this is called after the token is matched. But I want the user to enter a word in any cased and it should be matched with a rule. This page http://www.esiee.fr/~najmanl/compil/Flex/flex_2.html is talking about a macro, but not sure how to use it.

Comment: well this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @sap:  If you have a specific solution in mind, why ask the question?  This answers the question that you asked.

Comment: You can use `flex -i` to make pattern matching case insensitive, then you'd have to lowercase whatever you want to hand off elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you could redefine the [YY_INPUT](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html) macro in the top 'C' section:

```
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) \
        { \
        int c = '*', n; \
        for ( n = 0; n < max_size && \
                 (c = getc( yyin )) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++n ) \
            buf[n] = (char) tolower(c); \
        if ( c == '\n' ) \
            buf[n++] = (char)  tolower(c); \
        if ( c == EOF && ferror( yyin ) ) \
            YY_FATAL_ERROR( "input in flex scanner failed" ); \
        result = n; \
        }
```

Comment: Not a good idea, the details of said macro could very well be different in the next version of flex (or the prehistoric one you're forced to use when installing at Big Client's site).